# Fix Error with Left join

Tags: php, mysql

What is wrong with this command? I get error and not sure what is wrong

```
    $qrys = mysql_query("
    SELECT *
    FROM users
    LEFT JOIN follows ON follows.followbyid != '$userid' 
    WHERE users.active = 1 AND users.followex = 1 AND users.credits > 0 AND users.twid != '$userid' AND users.twimg != ''
    ORDER BY users.featured DESC, users.buyer DESC, users.retweets DESC 
    LIMIT 49
    ") or die (mysql_error());
```

Comment: Which error? Also, [obligatory Bobby Tables warning](http://bobby-tables.com).

Answer (score 0):

Should this not be:

```
   $qrys = mysql_query("
    SELECT *
    FROM users
    LEFT JOIN follows ON **[A JOIN CRITERIA]**
    WHERE users.active = 1 AND users.followex = 1 AND users.credits > 0 AND users.twid != '$userid' AND users.twimg != '' **AND follows.followbyid != '$userid'** 
    ORDER BY users.featured DESC, users.buyer DESC, users.retweets DESC 
    LIMIT 49
    ") or die (mysql_error());
```

Also stop using mysql_query and use mysqli at least.

Comment: So how i write criteria to get something like follows.followbyid != '$userid', actually to find if the $userid is not on the list of follows for particular row?

Comment: Can't you put it in the where section? like i did?